# Compute the support function, $\sigma_{C}$, when $C$ is a subspace.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, support-function

Recall that in convex analysis the support function is the conjugate of the indicator function and is defined to be $\sigma_{C}(x)=\sup_{v\in C} \langle v,x\rangle$. Compute the support function,  $\sigma_{C}$, when C is a subspace.

Please help me with starting this proof. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand at all the line $f^*(y) = \sup_c \langle v,x \rangle$ : the right side is free of $y$ and $f$, the supremum is taken over $c$ but there is no $c$ in $\langle v, x \rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in C^\perp$, then $x^Tv = 0$ for all $v \in C$ and so $i_C^*(x) = 0$. If $x \not \in C^\perp$,  then  $x^Tv_0 \not = 0$ for some $v_0 \in C\setminus\{0\}$. Now, it is clear that $v \mapsto x^Tv$ is unbounded on the line $L := \{tv_0 | t \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq C$. Thus $i_C^*(x) = +\infty$. Putting things together, we have $i_C^* = i_{C^\perp}$, as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

$\sigma_C=\iota_{C^\perp}$ where $C^\perp$ is the orthogonal of $C$ and $\iota_K$ is the indicator function of $K$